# Can't find the error in my text encoder program

Tags: c++, debugging, text, encoder

Just for fun, I've been working on a text encoding program that will scramble text.  I've got it working near flawlessly, but can't seem to get one bug worked out.  Basically, the text will encode and decode correctly for the most part, except once in a while, the program will decode the string with one letter out of place.  The code is kind of ugly, I haven't tried cleaning it up since I'm still working out the bugs, so my apologies for that.  It also is poorly copied and pasted in sections, so chance for optimization will be huge for me later down after I get it working correctly.  I have a feeling I know where the bug is, but making the correction I think needs to be made causes an endless loop.  Here is the code with some output at the bottom stored in a comment:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void FillKey(char Key2[]);

void Encrypt();
void EncryptMessage(char Key3[], char Input2[], char MessageEncrypted2[]);

void Decrypt();
void DecryptMessage(char Key4[], char CodedInput2[], char NormalOutput2[]);
char ReturnDecodedCharacter(char Key5[], char Character);

const int STRING_SIZE=500;
const int ASCII_RANGE_SIZE_94=94;//Range from ASCII value 32 to 126 = 94
const int SHIFT_SET_32=32;//Move range up 32 values form (0-93) to (32 to 126)

int main()
{
    int Choice;

    do
    {
        cout << "Press 1 to encrypt"      << endl;
        cout << "Press 2 to decrypt"      << endl;
        cout << "Press other key to quit" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Choice: ";

        cin >> Choice;

        if (Choice == 1)
            Encrypt();

        else if (Choice == 2)
            Decrypt();
    }

    while (Choice==1 || Choice == 2);
}

void Encrypt()
{
    int  SecretNumber;

    char Key[ASCII_RANGE_SIZE_94]={0};//One larger 0 - 93, not using 0
    char Input[STRING_SIZE]={0};
    char MessageEncrypted[STRING_SIZE]={0};

    cout << "\nEnter Secret Number: ";
    cin >> SecretNumber;

    cin.ignore(1);//removes newline from input buffer

    srand(SecretNumber);//Seed number for my random number generator

    FillKey(Key);

    cout << "\nInput message: ";

    cin.getline(Input, STRING_SIZE);

    EncryptMessage(Key, Input, MessageEncrypted);

    cout << "\nEncrypted Message(copy inside of parenthesis): " << "(" << MessageEncrypted << ")" << endl << endl;
}

void FillKey(char Key3[])
{
    int RandomNumber;
    int KeySpot, j;

    for (KeySpot=0; KeySpot<=ASCII_RANGE_SIZE_94; ++KeySpot)
    {
        RandomNumber = SHIFT_SET_32+rand()%ASCII_RANGE_SIZE_94;//0-93, then shifts up to 32-126 ASCII range

        for (j=0; j<=KeySpot; ++j)//this bit of code checks to make sure new rand number isn't already used before
        {
            if (Key3[j] == RandomNumber)
            {
                RandomNumber = SHIFT_SET_32+rand()%ASCII_RANGE_SIZE_94;//0-93, then shifts up to 32-126
                j=0;
            }
        }

        Key3[KeySpot] = (char) RandomNumber;
    }
}

void EncryptMessage(char Key3[], char Input2[], char MessageEncrypted2[])
{
    for (int i=0; Input2[i]; ++i)
    {
        MessageEncrypted2[i]= Key3[((int) Input2[i])-SHIFT_SET_32];//-32 to get range back into 1-95 (range of Key)
    }
}

void Decrypt()
{
    int SecretNumber;

    char Key[ASCII_RANGE_SIZE_94]={0};
    char EncryptedMessage[STRING_SIZE]={0};
    char DecodedMessage[STRING_SIZE]={0};

    cout << "\nEnter Secret Number: ";
    cin >> SecretNumber;

    cin.ignore(1);//removes newline from input buffer

    srand(SecretNumber);//Seed number for random number generator

    FillKey(Key);

    cout << "\nInput message to decode: ";

    cin.getline(EncryptedMessage, STRING_SIZE);

    DecryptMessage(Key, EncryptedMessage, DecodedMessage);

    cout << "\nDecoded Message: " << DecodedMessage << endl << endl;
}

void DecryptMessage(char Key4[], char EncryptedMessage2[], char DecodedMessage2[])
{
    for (int i=0; EncryptedMessage2[i]; ++i)
    {
        DecodedMessage2[i] = ReturnDecodedCharacter(Key4, EncryptedMessage2[i]);
    }
}

char ReturnDecodedCharacter(char Key5[], char Character)
{
    for (int Count=0; Count<=ASCII_RANGE_SIZE_94; ++Count)
    {
        if ((int) Character == Key5[Count])
        {
            return (char) Count+SHIFT_SET_32;//+32 to get back into 32-126 ASCII range
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

/*

Press 1 to encrypt
Press 2 to decrypt
Press other key to quit

Choice: 2

Enter Secret Number: 1

Input message to decode: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890

Decoded Message: Yj.63;nQb_ d"*!yTuc'8rTWi~1/|^ta5:?s+ODJwge42X,%q$SEvNZ9-h=kFL

Press 1 to encrypt
Press 2 to decrypt
Press other key to quit

Choice: 1

Enter Secret Number: 2

Input message: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890

Encrypted Message(copy inside of parenthesis): (oZs?=LtFPSk<B +j]&xf!}]1"yq;zQm8\:>|T7_56VRH{9D-/*aOdbGCgAnJuv)

Press 1 to encrypt
Press 2 to decrypt
Press other key to quit

Choice: 2

Enter Secret Number: 2

Input message to decode: oZs?=LtFPSk<B +j]&xf!}]1"yq;zQm8\:>|T7_56VRH{9D-/*aOdbGCgAnJuv

Decoded Message: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890

Press 1 to encrypt
Press 2 to decrypt
Press other key to quit

Choice: 1

Enter Secret Number: 3

Input message: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890

Encrypted Message(copy inside of parenthesis): (w?oGY`hn5Ty% L\Z$qrDHR$"!F=WX}IV-Nf|g&+(Ps.pM*S)1t/e2@9v067{KC)

Press 1 to encrypt
Press 2 to decrypt
Press other key to quit

Choice: 2

Enter Secret Number: 3

Input message to decode: w?oGY`hn5Ty% L\Z$qrDHR$"!F=WX}IV-Nf|g&+(Ps.pM*S)1t/e2@9v067{KC

Decoded Message: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890

Press 1 to encrypt
Press 2 to decrypt
Press other key to quit

Choice: 1

Enter Secret Number: 4

Input message: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890

Encrypted Message(copy inside of parenthesis): (2RQ%?u*"_yNXs!=t;VWb9);]:+#>dqv$wU7(EiP[JgGI&pxmh4\ eafk}0^1ln)

Press 1 to encrypt
Press 2 to decrypt
Press other key to quit

Choice: 2

Enter Secret Number: 4

Input message to decode: 2RQ%?u*"_yNXs!=t;VWb9);]:+#>dqv$wU7(EiP[JgGI&pxmh4\ eafk}0^1ln

Decoded Message:  bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890

Press 1 to encrypt
Press 2 to decrypt
Press other key to quit

Choice:

*/
```

If you notice, the last string (with secret number 4) didn't convert correctly and lost the initial 'a'.  I think the error is in the `void FillKey` function - inside the if statement `if (Key3[j] == RandomNumber)` I create a new random number and set `j=0` if any newly generated random number exactly the same as any of the previous ones in the key (can't have the same character twice, obviously).  So my thinking is, j is getting set to 0, but after the for loop, it gets incremented and becomes 1.  So the program isn't checking for duplicates in `Key3[3]`, so I changed the statement to `j=-1`, to anticipate it and get it back to zero after the for loop, but then the program gets stuck and never exists the loop.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is error here:

```
for (KeySpot=0; KeySpot<=ASCII_RANGE_SIZE_94; ++KeySpot)
```

It should be:

```
for (KeySpot=0; KeySpot < ASCII_RANGE_SIZE_94; ++KeySpot)
```

Because keysize is `ASCII_RANGE_SIZE_94`, that includes the zero index. The same error is in `ReturnDecodedCharacter`, it should be:

```
for (int Count=0; Count < ASCII_RANGE_SIZE_94; ++Count)
```

To make the code more easy to read, you could write as follows:

```
char ReturnDecodedCharacter(const char *key, int keysize, char Character)
{
    for (int Count = 0; Count < keysize; ++Count)
    {
        if (Character == key[Count])
        {
            return (char)(Count + SHIFT_SET_32);//+32 to get back into 32-126 ASCII range
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then pass `ASCII_RANGE_SIZE_94` as `keysize` when calling the function

---

This can also be done with XOR operator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void xor_with_cipher(const string &cipher, const string &src, string &dst)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < src.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = src[i] ^ cipher[i];
        dst.push_back(c);
    }
}

int main()
{
    string cipher;

    //create a simple cipher key with rand()
    //Note, rand **** should not **** be used in real cryptography applications
    int secretKey = 123;
    srand(secretKey);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        char c = rand() % 0xff;
        cipher.push_back(c);
    }

    string input = "plain text";
    string encoded;
    string decoded;

    //XOR cipher with input, create encoded
    xor_with_cipher(cipher, input, encoded);

    //XOR cipher with encoded, create decoded (decoded = input)
    xor_with_cipher(cipher, encoded, decoded);

    //encoded string is in binary, it may contain zero and non-printable characters
    //we can print the integer value of individual characters in encoded
    cout << "encoded: ";
    cout << hex << setfill('0');
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < encoded.length(); i++)
        cout << setw(2) << (encoded[i] & 0xff);
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "decoded: " << decoded << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Wow, that fixed it!  Well, that in combination with changing j=0 to j=-1.  Before, changing j=0 to j=-1 caused the program to get caught in a loop, but after seeing your fix and then implementing the j=-1, everything is working now.  At least it seems to be in my testing.  I'll also take a look at that bit of code cleanup you sent.  Thanks a bunch!  I doubt I could ever code as a profession, especially if I can't catch my own logic errors!

Comment: What is this for by the way, may I ask. It looks odd for homework, and it shouldn't be used in any real application. You could use XOR operator (`^`) to combine message with a secret cipher key, as long as cipher key is longer than message, and cipher key is used only once, the method will be secure. This method will produce binary result, but there are ways to convert it to text.

Comment: It is not a homework problem.  I just wanted to make it.  I'm studying programming in school and outside of my assigned homework, I supplement those with my own programs.  I just think of a program to make and attempt to make it.  Just to constantly keep using the programming information we learned.  I realize it's probably a poor method, but my goal was to just make the encoding program in general, as I wasn't able to in the past.

Comment: This looks like a modification of caesar or vigenere cipher. I added an XOR method which is used in modern cryptography. Although `rand` should not be used at all.

Comment: This is my first time dealing with encryption, so I'm not familiar with this area.  Any reason why we should use rand()? Too obvious?

Comment: In above example, the secret key for `srand` is a 32bit integer. Integer range is from zero to about 4 billion. New computers can go through 4 billion iterations in a few minutes. `rand` also has a predictable pattern, it can be hacked in much less than 4 billion iterations. New methods like AES use up to 256 bit key, and they are not predictable. By the way, AES is too complicated, I am not recommending it, it's just FYI

Comment: Makes sense. I appreciate the information.  I mostly made it as an exercise, for no practical reason.  I just wanted to see if I could make one that would simply change the text in a way average individuals couldn't read it.  I figured it wasn't secure at all :)